# When $|f(z)| \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-|z|^2}}$ on open unit disk $\mathbb{D}$ then $|f'(0)| \leq 2$

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, cauchy-integral-formula

I have to show, that if $|f(z)| \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-|z|^2}}$ on the open unit disk $\mathbb{D}$ then $|f'(0)| \leq 2$.

I thought I could use Cauchy's estimates theorem ,where $\left|f(z)\right| \le M$ and
$$
\left|f^{(n)}(z_0)\right| \le \frac{n! M}{R^n} \quad n \in \Bbb N, n \ge 1
$$ Here,  $z_0 = 0$ for all $z \in \mathbb{D}$ , the open unit disk:

$$
 f'(0) \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-|z|^2}}
$$

But obviously that isn't enough. So I suppose  by Cauchys Integral formula,
$$
 \left\lvert\, f'(0) \right|=\left\lvert\,\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=1}\!\frac{f(z)\,dz}{(z-0)^2}\right|\le max _{|z|=1} \left\lvert\, \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-|z|^2}} \frac{1}{z^2}  \right|
$$
I don't know how to go on. I would appreciate any hint.

Comment: your are not very careful with absolute values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relation shows that on the disc of radius $0<r<1$, $|f(z)| \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}$, so Cauchy shows that $|f'(0)| \le \frac{1}{r\sqrt{1-r^2}}$, where $r$ is arbitrary as above. Hence the hope is to show that for such an $r$ we get what we need.

But now it is obvious that the denominator is highest when $r^2=\frac{1}{2}$ and that for $r=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$ the inequality becomes precisely $|f'(0)| \le 2$, so we are done

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It's clear, but why do you get $|f'(0)| \le \frac{1}{r\sqrt{1-r^2}}$ and not $|f'(0)| \le \frac{1}{r^2\sqrt{1-r^2}}$?

Comment: Apply Cauchy - $\left|f^{(n)}(z_0)\right| \le \frac{n! M}{R^n} \quad n \in \Bbb N, n \ge 1$, with $z_0=0, n=1, R=r, M=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}$